# Changing Bootstrap's navbar opacity without affecting the buttons

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, opacity, navbar

I only want my navbar buttons to be visible, while the actual bar that spans across the entire page has full opacity.  Whenever I change the opacity of the navbar it affects the classes inside of it, even when I specify those classes to have no opacity.

I've posted an image of what I'm trying to replicate.  As you can see, the links appear in full, but the navbar is invisible, allowing the complete background image to show.  It might look like a solid red bar, but I assure you it's an invisible navbar.

[image]

Any help would be super appreciated!  Thanks.

---

Here's my navbar HTML code:

```
<div class="custom_nav">
    <div class="navbar navbar-fixed-top">
        <div class="navbar-inner">
            <div class="container">
                <a class="btn btn-navbar" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".nav-collapse">
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </a>
                <a class="brand" href="index.html">Homegrown</a>
            <div class="nav-collapse">
                <ul class="nav nav-pills">
                    <li class="active"><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
                    <li><a href="index.html">About</a></li>
                    <li><a href="index.html">Contact</a></li>
                </ul><!-- /.nav -->
            </div><!--/.nav-collapse -->
            </div><!-- /.container -->
        </div><!-- /.navbar-inner -->
    </div><!-- /.navbar -->
</div><!--/.custom_nav-->
```

So far I've tried editing my CSS with the following:

```
ul .nav .nav-pills {background:rgba(255,255,255,0.5)}

.custom_nav {
    .navbar.navbar-fixed-top {
        background:rgba(255,255,255,.5);
    }
    .navbar .nav > .active a, .navbar .nav > .active a:hover, .navbar .nav > li a:hover {
        background:rgba(210,105,30, 0); text-shadow:none;
    }   
}
```

Comment: Your question isn't very clear. Are you asking how to change the opacity of the parent without affecting the opacity of the children? You can use rgba for the background color (instead of opacity) if that's what you're going for. I would suggest posting a fiddle that demonstrates your problem.

Comment: The opacity property is propagated to its children. One way to solve this is to use the mechanism explained at http://www.impressivewebs.com/demo-files/css-opacity/

Comment: @ZakAngelle I'm attempting to do what the link in the comment below yours describes, but with the navbar being the parent and the buttons being the children class.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

One solution is to use [rbga](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-color/#rgb-color) as given [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2561460/css-opacity-and-child-elements). [It does not work in ie < 9](http://css-tricks.com/rgba-browser-support/),

```
.custom_nav .navbar.navbar-fixed-top .navbar-inner{
    background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.3);
}
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/NsFSL/2/)

Comment: I made some edits to my post to show how I have it set up and what I tired.

Answer (score 2):

To change the opacity of the parent without affecting the opacity of the children, use `rgba` on the background property, like this:

```
ul {
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.7);
}
```

The first 3 values are the RGB values that make up the color, and the last value is the opacity of the color (in the example above, the opacity is 70%).

See [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/A6r2J/).

Comment: I made some edits to my post to show how I have it set up and what I tried.

Answer (score 0):

I had write a mixin with stylu:

```
support-for-ie ?= true

opacity(n)
  opacity n
  -moz-opacity n
  filter unquote('alpha(opacity=' + round(n * 100) + ')')
  if support-for-ie
    filter unquote('progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=' + round(n * 100) + ')')

.opacity-70
  opacity(0.7)
```

I hope it can help someone who want some opacity with support almost all browser
thinks