# CSS: Issue with Opacity

Tags: html, css

I am working with website header and i needed to put some lines on a background of the header. Once i put it with some opacity i get a problem. All my header is under opacity now.

html:

```
<div class="header">
  <div clas="header strips">
     <div class="some_content"><lots of text</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

css:

```
.header
{
   height: 120px;
   width: 100%;
   float: left;
   background-color: #3A5FCD;
   background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #00BFFF,#3A5FCD );
}
.strips
{
    background: url(../img/picture.png);
    opacity: 0.3;
}
.some_content
{
   color: #FFFFFF;
   font-family: MaassslicerItalic;
   font-size: 20pt;
   border-bottom:5px  solid red;
}
```

i do not understand why my `<div class="some_content"><lots of text</div>` is also with opacity.

here is link to original website
http://portal.plazma.com.ua/

Comment: possible duplicate of [CSS opacity and child elements](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2561460/css-opacity-and-child-elements)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Child element always inherit the Opacity of the parent.

so you need to give the opacity like this `rgba(0,0,0,0.3)`

```
background: rgba(0,0,0,0.3) url(picture.png);
```

rgba==> a represents alpha

Try This For the background image

```
 .element {
        background: url(picture.png);

        background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.5);

    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Work with an rgba background-color.

Like so: `background-color: rgba(255,255,255,0.3)` The last number (0.3) is the opacity for the RGB color you specified.

Or, in short:

```
background: rgba(255,255,255,0.3) url(../img/picture.png);
```

Comment: but then it does not show my picture from 
background: url(../img/picture.png);

Answer (score 1):

You can use background-color opacity in CSS combined with your image.

```
.strips
{
    background: rgba(0,0,0,0.3) url(../img/picture.png);
}
```

Comment: but picture url(../img/picture.png); wount be under opacity

Comment: Can you set the opacity directly in the png?