# Select element loaded via Ajax by data attribute

Tags: jquery

I'm loading a number of nested divs via ajax and need to select specific elements by data attribute.  The code below works OK when changing the background of a div.

```
 $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "scripts/get_transcription.php",
    data: {
        gene: 1,
    },
    success: function(data) {
    $('#transcription').html(data);
    $('*[data-type="P"]').css('background', 'red');
}
  });
```

However, if instead of changing the background I want to say set opacity of that specific div, all the divs are assigned the opacity:

```
$('*[data-type="P"]').css({opacity, 0.5});
```

Same if I use `fadeOut()` on the div...all the divs fade out.  Why does css background work for the specific div and not opacity or fadeOut(which are applied to all the divs)?

**EDIT**

Looks like the ol' div not being closed catcha.  The closing div for each transcription_segment was outside the while loop as shown here:

```
echo "<div id='transcription_segments' style='width:2000px;;white-space:nowrap;float:left;'>";
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
echo "

<div id='transcription_segment_" . $row['gene_dna_segments_pk'] . "' data-transcription-segment='" . $row['gene_dna_segments_pk'] . "' data-type='"  . substr($row['dna_segment_type'], 0, 1) . "' style='width:" . $row['dna_segment_length'] . "px;display:inline-block;'>

<div style='width:" . $row['dna_segment_length'] . "px; height:auto;font-family: Delicious, sans-serif;font-size:16px;color:" . $row['colour'] . ";text-align:center;font-weight:bold;line-height:1.4;float:left;'>" . $row['dna_segment_type'] . "</div>

<div style='width:" . $row['dna_segment_length'] . "px;height:12px;background:" . $row['colour'] . "; float:left'></div>";
}
echo "</div></div>";
?>
```

Comment: CSS element opacity is multiplied down through child elements so it will effect all child elements inside the div's. refer this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2561460/css-opacity-and-child-elements   Also js fadeout will fadeout div with its all inner content.

Comment: Well that's what I expect to happen, but it looks like its being applied to the parent div, as all nested divs with data value other than 'P' are being faded out.

Comment: This page has a fix to this but it isn't pretty. http://www.impressivewebs.com/css-opacity-that-doesnt-affect-child-elements/

Comment: @peter umm just a concern your div tags with data-type="" attr donot have closing div's.

Comment: Accidently omitted while putting together the examples...they exist in the php generated divs...

Comment: Neha - Checking php file...oops, the closing divs for the transcription_segment divs is actually outside of the while loop.  That has fixed the problem!  Please put your comment into an answer!  Many thanks for spotting this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Missing closing div's are causing the issue into js element selector.

Answer (score 0):

How does the response look like?

```
$('*[data-type="P"]').css({opacity, 0.5});
```

Will respectively affect all elements with the specific data attribute.

Comment: This gets applied to all the divs, not just the div with data value of 'P'

Comment: Ahh the problem seems to lie in the formatting:

It needs to be:
**$('*[data-type="P"]').css('opacity', 0.5);**

Here is a working fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/K4Hg8/

Comment: No, the opacity is applied to all nested divs not just data value 'P'.  See OP for edit.

Answer (score 0):

your code is correct but I did not a get chance to debug it, but here is quick solution. I think you can solve it by following css line

```
div[data-type="P"]{opacity:0.5;}
```

Have a nice day!